# How to check_object_permissions on @api_view functions?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I defined a view function with the `@api_view` decorator. Now I would like to test object-level permissions in this object.

I know there is a `check_object_permissions` that would let me check the permissions I defined on my view, but I don't know how to call it. The documentation gives examples for classes, not functions.

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated & IsOwnerOfItem])
def query_something_related_to_items(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)

    # I want to test IsOwnerOfItem here,
    # I guess I need to call something like:
    # "self".check_object_permissions(request, item)

    # custom code here

    return something

class IsOwnerOfItem(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) says:

> If you're writing your own views and want to enforce object level permissions, or if you override the get_object method on a generic view, then you'll need to explicitly call the .check_object_permissions(request, obj) method on the view at the point at which you've retrieved the object.

But how do you call this in an view function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the documentation you referred says:

> Object level permissions are run by REST framework's **generic views**
> when .get_object()

So, class based views are meant in there. In order to check object permissions in function based view, you should write your logic and raise `PermissionDenied` if you decide that `request` shouldn't access `item`. Pseudocode:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# I want to test IsOwnerOfItem here,
# I guess I need to call something like:
# `has_permission_for_item` is your own function
if not has_permission_for_item(request, item):
    raise PermissionDenied()
```